# InvalidArgument exception come from objectlistview when form disposed

Tags: c#, objectlistview

There

I have a windows form which embedded a objectlistview in it.

I get an exception:

************** Exception Text **************

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
at BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.GetColumn(Int32 index)
at BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.EditSubItem(OLVListItem item, Int32 subItemIndex)
at BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.WmReflectNotify(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.WndProc(Message& m)
at BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

---

**Test case:**

I trigger the cell_click event of the objectlistview and popup a modal in the event handler.
I have a System.Windows.Form.Timer for timeout count down, I disposed all open forms when time is up, and then the exception as above happen on.

**Additional comments:**

1. When I click the cell which have no value in it, the exception does not happen, it only happen when I click cell which has value.
2. What I don't understand is: when I debug in VS, there is no exception, but it only happen when I run it by double clicking app.exe from the debug path.

Is there anybody could provide help on this, provide a debug method or any help would be appreciate.thanks.

Comment: You could try running with [the source code for ObjectListView rather than the binary](http://sourceforge.net/projects/objectlistview/files/objectlistview/2.8.0/ObjectListView-2.9.0.zip/download) then you can set breakpoints ni e.g. `GetColumn`

Comment: Thanks so much, it seems a bug of objectlistview, I will post it into sourceforge.net